# Determine if a a fie is printable

Tags: file, text, ascii, control-characters

I'm writing a code that receives a file/byte array from multiply operation system and like to determine if such input is printable as a file.

From the ASCII table we know that control character range is 0-31 but:

Horizontal Tab = 9 and printable in a file.
Line Feed = 10 and printable in a file.

Form Feed = 12 and printable in a file.
Carriage Return = 13 and printable in a file.

Delete = 127 and non printable.

Am I missing something? Is there a well known definition for a file to be printable?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters

Comment: @dave Thanks but I know that and already wrote it on the question. I like for a explanation about the control char that are used in text files.

Comment: What do you mean by "is printable as a file"? All files are binary. Some are text. Each text file was written with one specific character encoding. If you don't know what it is then you can't read it as the writer intended. You can always read it, perhaps incorrectly, with the OEM437 or ISO 8859-1 character encodings. You can't always read it with the ASCII encoding (but who uses ASCII anyway). You can convert control characters to [control picture](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2400.pdf) characters and print them if you want.